# Is there any way to view pdf below lollipop android?

Tags: android, pdf

I want to show pdf data to user I tried some approaches but they are not supported below lollipop. Is there any way that can show pdf data.

Comment: Use a third party library.  There's a variety of them, some free some paid.

Comment: You can try this library https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

Comment: will the library support to all lover devices, I mean those are in market.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this library

https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

I have used this library in few of my projects and it works just fine.

Also it supports all versions of android from 11.

To use it just write

```
  pdfView.fromUri(Uri)
  or
 pdfView.fromFile(File)
 or
 pdfView.fromAsset(String)
.pages(0, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3) // all pages are displayed by default
.enableSwipe(true)
.enableDoubletap(true)
.swipeVertical(false)
.defaultPage(1)
.showMinimap(false)
.onDraw(onDrawListener)
.onLoad(onLoadCompleteListener)
.onPageChange(onPageChangeListener)
.onError(onErrorListener)
.enableAnnotationRendering(false)
.password(null)
.showPageWithAnimation(true)
.load();
```

If still the solution is unclear follow the given sample with the library.
Mark this accepted if this helps so that it can help others too.

Comment: I am getting issues with onDrawListener and all other methods of interface. Which interface needs to be implemented.

Answer (score 2):

You can use third party library and some are free available. 
Please follow this step for [Mupdf](http://ssahinkoc.blogspot.in/2014/10/integration-of-mupdf-project-as-library.html) integration

Answer (score 0):

following are ways to open pdf below lollipop version,

```
1) make use of third party libraray
2) pass the pdf url to google docs and open it in webview
3) by passing intent open it into pdf application like pdfViewer etc
```